# I need the logo to overlap the navbar

Tags: html, css

I want the logo to overlap my navbar like this:

[image]

So far I have this:
[image]

As you can see the logo just make the navbar bigger, how do I make the logo overlap the navbar?
The codepen is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvqbLo

I think the problem is with the CSS:

```
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Rather than changing positioning like the answers below, it's also valid to give your logo a negative bottom margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the option:

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
.topnav .logo { position: absolute; z-index:1; top:0; }
.topnav .nav { padding-left: 360px; }
.topnav ul.nav li { float: left; list-style:none; }
.topnav .nav a {
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
  color: #333;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .topnav {
    background-color: #134095;
  }

  .topnav a {
    color: white;
  }
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#home" class="logo" style="z-index:1;position:absolute;"><img src="https://preview.c9users.io/jafar70/toucan-tech/navimg.jpg"></a>
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li><a href="#contact">lorem ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">lorem ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">lorem ipsum</a></li>
              </ul>
                
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="learn-more">
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div class="container">
            <p class="title">Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede</p>
            <p class="lead">Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
            <button class="btn"><div>Call to action <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon=">"></span></div></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

P.S: view it in full screen, not really responsive optimized at this point.

Comment: Thanks I added style="position: absolute; z-index:1; top:0;" to the logo, now it works

Answer (score 1):

logo should be `float: left`  and menu tabs should be `float:right`

```
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
   background-color: #134095;
  margin-left:3px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Also updated at [coded your link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvqbLo)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap then you can do this also:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">ADD LOGO HERE</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">ADD NAV HERE (adjust the left margin to -5px or -10px on col-md-10)

    </div>
</div>
```

And for z-index to apply, you have to put position(absolute,relative or fixed).
else it wont work.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is not in CSS code, it is in the HTML instead. Because you place your logo image in the same 'div' container with the navigation bar items. Thus your logo can not be bigger than navigation 'DIV'.
Try to place your logo image in separate 'DIV'.
Or just place your mountains image (as in your example how it should look like) below logo and with negative margin with CSS:

```
 .mountainsDiv { margin-top: -85px; }
```

Now your text will overlap with logo image. You can solve it with padding in your paragraph '  and for CSS:

```
 .mountainsP { padding: 90px 10px; }
```

I hope that will help :)

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution is to place background image of mountains below the navigation bar with ' z-index:-1 ' and with a ' margin-top: -80px ' (not sure how much pixels of margin you will need, need to experiment with it) style atributes in CSS.